# An "el" header must exist in DOM

Tags: jasmine, marionette, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I'm using grunt-contrib-jasmine to do testing with Marionette. My specs pass but I get this error: 'Error: An "el" header must exist in DOM' at the Marionette source. I can't track down the problem

My grunt config is:

```
jasmine : {
      src : [
        'common/js/app.js',
        'common/js/model/*.js',
        'common/js/collection/*.js',
        'common/js/view/*.js',
        'common/js/route/route.js'
      ],
      options : {
        '--web-security' : false,
        '--local-to-remote-url-access' : true,
        '--ignore-ssl-errors' : true,
        specs : 'test/spec/*.js',
        vendor: [
          'bower_components/jquery-2.1.0.min/index.js',
          'bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
          'bower_components/sinonjs/sinon.js',
          'bower_components/jasmine-sinon/lib/jasmine-sinon.js',
          'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
          'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          'bower_components/backbone/backbone.js',
          'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js',
          'bower_components/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.min.js'
        ],
        host:  'http://localhost:3000'
      }
```

Comment: Do you have any regions with the selector 'header' ? e.g. `regions: {
        'headerRegion' : 'header'
      }`

Comment: What are you using for a headless DOM?